# Using Chinese M Business visa when now working for a different company

Tags: visas, china, business-travel

Can a Business China Visa (category M, 10 year validity) obtained while working for one company be used for a trip on behalf of another company?

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, you can still use it**.  The M visa is a standard business visa for "commercial and trade activities", it's not tied to the entity that initially issued the invitation for you:

http://cs.mfa.gov.cn/wgrlh/lhqz/lhqzjjs/t1095035.shtml

Note that on arrival, it's technically possible that you'll be asked for some sort of proof that you're visiting China for business reasons, but in my own limited experience I've never been asked anything at all by immigration in China. YMMV.